# Why is my background-image not displayed when uploaded to bluemix single sign on?

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

Bluemix SSO provides the ability to download a zip file containing the html and style.css files to enable users to customize their pages.  This is great!  However I can't seem to get it to work.  I updated the proper login.html and the equivalent style.css file.  It displays properly in my browser, but when I upload the files back to bluemix SSO, the page info and setup shows up as expected but the background jpg image is not there.

snipt from my style.css:

```
body {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url('./my.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Is there a specific place we need to put these files?
I've tried:
  * background-image: url('./my.jpg');
  * background-image: url(my.jpg);
  * background-image: url(/mtfim/sps/static/my.jpg); 
      -- /mtfim/sps/static is the location where the html seem to be picking up the style.css file

I'm out of ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, and not only with Bluemix, if you need to understand where to put an image or a generic resource for a web page to load it through the web browser, the best and quickest way is to use the developer tool from Chrome/Firefox/IE and check the URL used by the browser to fetch the resource using the network panel or the inspection one: by this way you have immediately the path where the browser looks for the resource and you habe simply to put the image here.

From your first CSS you are referring a jpg placed in the same path of the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Well instead of saying:

```
background-image: url('./my.jpg');
```

say:

```
background-image: url(localhost/my.jpg); <!--This is for localhosted website -->
```

or

```
background-image: url(Your Link/my.jpg); <!--This is for online hosted services! -->
```

Comment: Also if you do not have any hosts at all use:

background-image: url(file:///Location to the file/my.jpg);

Comment: This is an website that is hosted on bluemix and uses the SSO service so I'm not sure the online hosted services example would work... However, I tried the following:
1. put the jpg in my web server dir public/image
2. in SSO style.css file: updated background-image to url(www.myserver.com/public/image/my.jpg)
Still didn't work :(

Comment: the location "public" is the root folder :D so do www.myserver.com/image.jpg if it is there :D

Comment: And also you can add a new folder in the public folder called imgs thenput all your imaged in there and say: background-image: url(http://myserver.com/imgs/my.jpg);

Comment: That worked!!  Thx so much!!  
FYI, I found out that although we can modify the templates provided by SSO, we can NOT add any files!!  So an external file path is the only way to do it.